# To rsync -rtvuc in Two Filesystems?

Tags: filesystems, rsync

Systems

- OS_X_Extended/Source/
- FAT32/Destination/

I want to rsync everything from OSX extended to Fat32 directory and delete those files/directories which I deleted from OSX_extended. I would like to  maintain the *modification time* (`-t`). I look hashes of files (`-c`), ignoring owners and groups. 
My proposal

```
rsync -rtvuc --delete --progress $HOME/Source/ /media/masi/FAT32/Destination/
```

which also includes .dotFiles in the process.

---

How can you rsync with modification times two directories in two filesystems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you shared will sync `/media/masi/fat32/destinationDirectory/` (destination)
on the basis of $`HOME/SourceDirectory/` (source) and will delete those which from destination which are in extra in comparison to source.

```
> --progress  : will show you the process progress
> -r : recursively
> -t  --times : This tells rsync to transfer modification times along with the files and update
>     them on the remote syste
> -c  --checksum This forces the sender to checksum all files using a 128-bit MD4  checksum before transfer
> -u -- update This forces rsync to skip any files for which the destination file already exists and has a date later than the source
> file.


rsync -rtvuc --delete --progress $HOME/SourceDirectory/ /media/masi/fat32/destinationDirectory/
```

Comment: It seems to work. Modification time too.

Comment: I extended the case to a situation where I do not want to delete those files of existing in the destination. I also revered FAT32 to be the source, here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287640/16920