# How to take tarball of directories with circular symlinks?

Tags: debian, tar, symlink

I create a backup by the following command as root (TODO right? because roaima observes that this can cause a complication) in a directory tree which has circular symlinks in some directories; those directories, `tar` skips. 
Command 1 which output in Fig. 1

```
root@masi:/home/masi# tar czf /media/masi/ext4Masi/backup_home_20.12.2016.tar.gz $HOME/
```

Characteristics of the system

- `$HOME/Documents/`

  ```
  masi@masi:~$ ls -ld /home/masi/Documents/
  drwxr-xr-x 36 masi masi 4096 Nov 23 22:02 /home/masi/Documents/
  ```
- `$HOME`

  ```
  masi@masi:~$ echo $HOME
  /home/masi
  ```

Fig. 1 Output of Command (1) AND output of Command (2) (same output), 
Fig. 2 Home tree

[image]
[image]

Characteristics of tarballs

- Tarball from Command 1; same case for Command 2. It indicates no `Documents` directory in the backup.

  ```
  root@masi:/home/masi/Documents/bin# tar tzvf /media/masi/masiWeek/backup_home_22.12.2016.tar.gz | grep 'Documents/*$' 
  root@masi:/home/masi/Documents/bin#
  ```

If circular symlink to the directory, `tar` skips the directory, in my case, `Documents`. 
Other directory, `Downloads`, is then again backup. 
I would like to avoid this behaviour. 
You can do `--deference` for a workaround but it is main disadvantage is duplicate data i.e. deferencing the symlinks which I would like to maintain in my backups too.

Command 2, but fails, output in Fig. 1 too

```
# DopeGhoti
root@masi:/home/masi/Documents/bin# nice tar czf \
    /media/masi/masiWeek/backup_home_22.12.2016.tar.gz \
    --keep-directory-symlink $HOME/
```

Command 3, but fails, output same in Fig. 1 too

```
root@masi:/home/masi# nice tar --keep-directory-symlink -czf \ 
  /media/masi/masiWeek/backup_home_22.12.2016.tar.gz $HOME/
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Related: to restore such a backup in the thread [How to recover home backup into almost new Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331726/16920)

Comment: `tar` will just store the symlinks, not interpret/traverse them (unless asked to).

Comment: The command that you have does not create a zipped file, so you will not want to end file name with `.gz`

Comment: Are the symlink pointing to out side of the backed up directory tree, when you see the missing directories?

Comment: Just use `tar --keep-directory-symlink`?

Comment: Output of `ls-ld Documents` and `tar tzvf /media/masi/ext4Masi/backup_home_20.12.2016.tar.gz | grep 'Documents/*$'` please

Comment: @Masi, your incovation has the switch in the wrong location.  Try `tar --keep-directory-symlink -czf /path/to/tarball.tgz $HOME/`.

Comment: You will get that if you use `czf` rather than `-czf`; I rapidly fixed my comment but you may have seen the earlier version before I could make the correction.

Comment: @roaima Please, see the body for the outputs.

Comment: Um. You are running the `tar cvf ...` as yourself, rather than `root`, aren't you...? The backup appears to contain `root`'s directory rather than yours, which is indicative of `HOME=/root` rather than `HOME=/home/masi`

Comment: @roaima I run the backup as root, not as myself. The backup do contains `root` directory. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you confirm that you're running the backup as the `root` user rather than as yourself. When you become the `root` user, your value of `$HOME` also changes. (This is affected by the way in which you become `root`.)

Thus, when you run `tar cvf /tmp/backup.tar $HOME` you get the `$HOME` directory for `root`. What has been very confusing in your question (and the [linked one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331726/16920)) is that you have been interchanging `$HOME` and `/home/masi`.

To backup `/home/masi` you should use something like `tar cvf /tmp/backup.tar /home/masi`. Or change the means by which you become the `root` user so that `$HOME` is not changed too.

When you backup the correct directory tree I suspect you'll find your missing `Documents` folder.

Comment: How can you change your way of becoming root without changing `$HOME`?

Comment: Can `--keep-directory-symlink` be necessary in taking such backups here in any cases?

Comment: @Masi what command or process do you use to become the `root` user?

Comment: Just the command `su`.

Comment: @Masi `man su` says (amongst other things) « _The `$HOME`, `$SHELL`, `$USER`, `$LOGNAME`, `$PATH`, and `$IFS` environment variables are reset._ ». It also says you can use `-m` or `-p` to avoid this reset, ie `su -p`. One question I would ask you to consider is whether you really need to take the backup as `root` in the first place; after all, you already own the files being backed up.